# GameplayKit: Fine tune control of GKAgent

Tags: xcode, swift, sprite-kit, xcode7, gameplay-kit

I'm testing out gameplaykit using spritekit.  I've added a `GKAgent` to my `GKEntity` and I am making my Entity seek my touches by creating an `endAgent` at touch position.

This works great.  The agent moves naturally and chases my touches.  However, I have two questions..

How can I stop the agent when it reaches its destination.  The agent will circle around forever trying to exactly land on the point.   I've tried `agent.behavior.removeAllGoals()`  I'd figure that would stop the agent right away since it has no goals.. but nothing happens.

Second question is how can I fine tune movement.  An agent would be ideal for something like a missile chasing an airplane.  The problem is that it decelerates when reaching its target.  The movement pattern is so specific.  I've tried playing with the properties `mass`, `maxSpeed` `maxAcceleration` etc..  Anything I'm missing?

Comment: Agents for missiles won't work well, you'll be better off with a "homing" movement algorithm, ie consistent speed and turn rate where the object tries to rotate in direction of target. For reaching the target a simple distance check (radius) should work but no idea if an agent is supposed to stop if it has no goals anymore - perhaps remove the agent component itself?

Comment: that's too bad..  I have an algorithim for that I've written in the past, but I was trying to see how agents could help me avoid writing some complicated movement code in the future.  Hard to find good information on GKAgent beyond the basics..

Answer (score 1):

The API describes agents in terms of their motivation, but in some ways they act more like physics bodies — that is, they follow Newton's First Law and stay in motion unless "motivated" to change their speed or direction.

To stop an agent when it reaches its destination, you need to make stopping be its primary goal. Check per-frame what your distance to the target is, and when you get "close enough" (whatever counts as that for your gameplay), take out the seek goal and replace it with a target-speed goal whose speed is zero.

For the "heat-seeking missile" behavior, you might try using an [intercept-agent](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GameplayKit/Reference/GKGoal_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/GKGoal/goalToInterceptAgent:maxPredictionTime:) goal instead of a seek-agent goal and varying the prediction time to see how that affects the pursuit speed. (And you probably don't need the missile to remain in the scene once it gets close enough to the airplane, so if you can limit the slowdown to "within explosion distance" you can ignore it.)

Comment: I really can't get for what reason on the earth they will never stop.